# Is is possible to save blocks from one mailing to reuse in another mailing using CiviCRM Mosaico?

Tags: mailing, mosaico

I have two different newsletters – a monthly one to our full mailing list and a weekly one every other week to a smaller group. They use different templates so I cannot simply reuse a weekly issue as a monthly issue or vice versa, but I often need to repeat selected blocks (Mosaico) of content in both. At the moment, I am laboriously copying each element (title, text, button text, button link, image) from one mailing to the next, but this is really time-consuming.
Is there a way to copy a block from one mailing into another mailing, eg by copy and paste or saving to a library?

Answer (score 2):

One way that I  am aware of is to click into a block in one mailing and then select the "Source" button 
[image]

That will bring up the HTML source code dialog window [image]

You could copy this, and then paste it into a block on the other mailing and assuming there are no fundamental differences in the template's stylesheet, it should look the same.